# Are there Drupal modules that help process e-mails dynamically

Tags: emails

I had the idea of implementing a workflow module for e-mail communications, something like this:

User role 1 can write e-mails (as nodes or custom entities)
User role 2 can review and approve e-mails
User role 3 can press send

I would then like the website to catch replies and enter them into the database with reference to the user entities that touched the e-mail entity, so that the workflow can also be applied to replies.
The part that I'm not sure I can do here, is doing advanced e-mail processing based on which users touched the e-mail.

Are there any modules that can handle encoding these entity references into the reply-to or message of the e-mail so that the Drupal site can process the replies dynamically?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on books, tools, modules, themes, distributions, tutorials, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Inmail](https://www.drupal.org/project/inmail) is designed to be the low level framework to receive mails within Drupal. We proposed in D8 to also implement [Mailhandler](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailhandler) on top of Inmail and there's good chance this will happen to reduce complexity.

Inmail "works" and you can write plugins to handle the mails.

What you need is a system that supports dynamic mail addresses (through e.g. address expansion). They then need to be redirected / forwarded to the site. This is more a mail server (MTA) configuration than inmail on its own. Through this, every reply is sent to a unique mail address (defined when sending). You can then while handling the mail easily lookup the reference / know the origin.

We plan to add more support for common mail configuration to consider these dynamic situations through configuration only at some point.

Check the issue queue, open feature requests if you can't find a proper issue and start contributing to it! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For drupal 8 there is the module [Inmail](https://www.drupal.org/project/inmail) that sound promising:

> The purpose of Inmail is to process process incoming email and execute certain actions depending on the content of each message (…)

For drupal 7 there is a.f.a.i.k currently only [Mailhandler](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailhandler) that would offer functionalities which would allow similar workflows:

> Mailhandler uses Feeds to let you post nodes by email. It takes mail (usually from an IMAP mailbox) and imports it as whatever type of content you choose#

I must admit doubt that either of them is capable of what you call *'advanced e-mail processing'*. However – maybe something similar can be achieved when combining either of the above modules with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).

Comment: Thx, I didnt know Inmail and it seems to be made for just what I want to do. I think mailhandler and rules could probably also do it as I've seen similar functionality in Drupal sites and these are the tools to do it with, but I suspect it will require a lot of work with the D7 tools